# CSS grid unproperly spaced

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with three items, and the last two are "spaced upwards" for some reason.

```css
.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-areas: "name edit remove"
}

.item-name {
  grid-area: name;
}

.item-edit {
  grid-area: edit;
}

.item-remove {
  grid-area: remove;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p class="item-name">1 Arrow</p>
  <a class="item-edit" href="#">Edit</a>
  <a class="item-remove" href="#">Remove</a>
</div>
```

The "Edit" and "Remove" are spaced upwards instead of on the same line as the "1 Arrow".

Comment: That's because you have a paragraph which comes with a default margin. Remove it and they line up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As @j08691 already said its because of your
>   [`<p>`-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) which comes with a default
>   [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

---

You could easily 'fix' it by adding `margin: 0;` to your class `.item-name` like i did below. Or you could put your links into a paragraph, too. Like `<p class="item-edit"><a href="#">Edit</a></p>`

```css
.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-areas: "name edit remove"
}

.item-name {
  grid-area: name;
  margin: 0;
}

.item-edit {
  grid-area: edit;
}

.item-remove {
  grid-area: remove;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p class="item-name">1 Arrow</p>
  <a class="item-edit" href="#">Edit</a>
  <a class="item-remove" href="#">Remove</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `align-items: center;`

```css
.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-areas: "name edit remove";
  align-items: center;
}

.item * {border: solid 1px orange; } /* added only for demonstration purpose*/

.item-name {
  grid-area: name;
}

.item-edit {
  grid-area: edit;
}

.item-remove {
  grid-area: remove;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p class="item-name">1 Arrow</p>
  <a class="item-edit" href="#">Edit</a>
  <a class="item-remove" href="#">Remove</a>
</div>
```

if you don't use it (like what you had) with the orange border it looks like so:

```css
.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-areas: "name edit remove";
}

.item * {border: solid 1px orange; } /* added only for demonstration purpose*/

.item-name {
  grid-area: name;
}

.item-edit {
  grid-area: edit;
}

.item-remove {
  grid-area: remove;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p class="item-name">1 Arrow</p>
  <a class="item-edit" href="#">Edit</a>
  <a class="item-remove" href="#">Remove</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-areas: "name edit remove"
}

.item-name {
  grid-area: name;
}

.item-edit {
  grid-area: edit;
}

.item-remove {
  grid-area: remove;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <label class="item-name">1 Arrow</label>
  <a class="item-edit" href="#">Edit</a>
  <a class="item-remove" href="#">Remove</a>
</div>
```

Try label tag